# How to fetch different HTTP headers from decodeHeaders in Envoy filter?

Tags: envoyproxy

I am working on developing a HTTP filter in Envoy proxy.
As part of DecodeHeaders, my intention is to extract URI path, HTTP method,  request headers starting with X-,  URI query parameters and the host name.

Are there any helper functions available to extract these given the 'headers' argument that is passed to the DecodeHeaders?